# Bootstrap not working inside pdf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pdf, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, mpdf

This is my controller code

```
public function actionPrint_death_certificate1()
    {

        $this->layout   =   'certificate';


        $html   =   $this->render('test');
        require_once(Yii::$app->basePath . "/../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php");
        $mpdf=new mPDF();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output();

    }
```

My view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        Heading1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        Heading2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i get a pdf with heading1 and heading2 in two different lines. Bootstrap is not working. Am i missing something?

```
return $this->render('test');
```

When i tried this one it is working and heading1 and heading2 is coming in one line. In pdf it is not working

Comment: mPDF has limited css support, and most likely bootstrap's grid will not work there. Do it the old fashioned way with a table: `<table><tr><td>Heading1</td><td>Heading2</td></tr></table>`.

Comment: that's so sad to hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an issue in github and mpdf guys told that **bootstrap not supported out-of-the-box** inside mpdf and you have to use some custom style. [Github link](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/66)

Answer (score 1):

From @Bloodhound post - this solution works for me well

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `$mpdf->WriteHtml($stylesheet, 1)` to add custom stylesheets within your pdf,  for more information you can check this link http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=254

```
public function actionPrint_death_certificate1()
{
    $this->layout = 'certificate';
    $html = $this->render('test');
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');
    require_once(Yii::$app->basePath . "/../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php");
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. please check this link https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

Guys i figured out this is caused by the print styles of the bootstrap framework.

Adding this to the stylesheet solves the problem for me :)

```css
@media print {
    @page {
        size: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's great that you found correct answer by yourself! Can you please add this to the question as well?