# Media query is giving me XS when converting my page to PDF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pdf, media-queries

I'm using bootstrap 3 in my project, when I try to convert to PDF, all my fields go as if I were in Cel.

Now, just to check, I changed all my md- to xs- so now, in web, it never goes to cell responsiveness. But in my pdf, it still have cell responsiveness, which is pretty annoying. 
I can solve it via tables, but I just lose all responsiveness. Maybe it is a good behavior for cell, but for A4 PDF, I could force 2 columns without any problem
How should I solve it?

Here is a piece of my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="championship" class="text-bold">Championship</label>:
            <input class="form-control sheet_championship" name="championship" type="text" value="Individual Men" id="championship">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shiajo" class="text-bold">Shiajo</label>:
            <input class="form-control sheet_shiajo" name="shiajo" type="text" value="1" id="shiajo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="group" class="text-bold">Group</label>:
            <input class="form-control sheet_group" name="group" type="text" value="1" id="group">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="writer" class="text-bold">Writer</label>:
            <input class="form-control sheet_writer" name="writer" type="text" value="" id="writer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean for cel responsiveness? thanks

Comment: well, it goes to a xs layout, 1 field per line, in PDF, I want to force layout to have 2 columns

Comment: I found this discussion of 1 year ago saying that bootstrap does not support out of the box pdf, but you can create specific css..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705495/bootstrap-not-working-inside-pdf 
What do you think?

Comment: sounds accurate!

Comment: I think you should be able to use media query for mobiles 
`@media (max-width: 360px) { }` so that their `width: 360px;` while for md and lg I don't know. Usually col-md-6 has `width:50%, display: block-inline; ` while the row it is included in `width: 100%; display: block;`